# GTK Linux application prior to gdm login remains on screen at login after program ends

Tags: linux, login, gtk, x-server

I have a GTK Linux application which I want to use as an "Accept Terms of Usage" screen prior to the user logging in.  The application is simple, a big Box with a Label and an Acknowledge button on the bottom.  When the user clicks it the processing continues on to the gdm login screen.

The name of my application is `/usr/bin/consent`, I am using `/usr/libexec/gdmlogin` and I have added have added `/usr/bin/consent` as the last line in the `/etc/gdm/Init/Default` file.

My Problem:

The application executes fine, before anything else, the user clicks "I Acknowledge" and everything continues on to the gdmlogin screen, BUT, it is almost as if X takes a snapshot of the GTK window and places it in the upper-left corner. So now in the background, I am looking at my Acknowledgement GUI.  In a process listing the application is terminated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue although I'm not sure why `gdm` behaves this way.  I had a gdm background image defined, the gnome foot, so when I went in and removed the login background image from the gdm login screen things worked fine.